# regionCode will be deprecated in iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios16

From iOS 16, `regionCode`depricated when try to access `regionCode` from current locale.
Like this code

```
let locale = Locale.current
locale.regionCode
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution for **iOS 16 and earlier version**

```
    let locale = Locale.current
    var countryCode = ""
    if #available(iOS 16, *) {
        if let value = locale.region?.identifier {
            countryCode = value
        }
    } else {
        if let value = locale.regionCode {
            countryCode = value
        }
    }
    print(countryCode)
```